# NLog Programmatically configured Archiving doesn't work with Mono

Tags: logging, f#, mono, nlog

My problem is that NLog with Mono appears to break log archiving when using programmatic configuration.  I'm not sure if it's an issue with my configuration code or Mono or something else.  Non-archiving logging works, so it's probably not a permissions issue.  This works in Windows with Visual Studio, so it's probably not an issue with NLog or the configuration setup.

I'm working on setting up a library which requires that the NLog logger be programmatically configured.  This logger must be setup with a rolling log file.  I put together this small test program in C# and tested in Windows and the rolling log file works.

When I run on Linux or OSX with mono, the rolling log file does not work.  The logger works and writes to the log file up until the file size limit is hit.  At that point, instead of creating the archive log file, the logging just stops completely.

```
let private createFileTarget filename =
    let target = new Targets.FileTarget()
    let logFile = filename + ".log"
    printfn "Logging to %s" logFile
    target.FileName <- new SimpleLayout(logFile)
    target.Layout <- new SimpleLayout("${message}")
    target.ArchiveFileName <- new SimpleLayout(filename + ".{#}.log")
    target.MaxArchiveFiles <- 3
    target.ArchiveNumbering <- ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling
    target.ConcurrentWrites <- true
    target.KeepFileOpen <- true
    target.ArchiveAboveSize <- 1024L * 1024L
    target

let private configure () =
    let config = new LoggingConfiguration()
    let target = createFileTarget "test"
    config.AddTarget("logfile", target)

    let rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, target)
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule)

    let factory = new LogFactory()
    factory.Configuration <- config
    factory.GetLogger("testLogger")
```

Comment: I would suspect the Linux [file creation flags](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) in particular "O_APPEND". Try adding the Unix or Linux tag and let them have a look.

Comment: If it were me I would download the NLog source code, build, and debug with the source code. Since it is reproducible it should be easy to find.

Comment: It is advisable to check the internal log: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting#internal-logging. Also try the lastest rc (4.3), a lot file archiving bugs are fixed: http://nlog-project.org/2016/03/23/nlog-4-3-0-RC-is-now-available.html

Comment: PS. Instead of `new SimpleLayout("${message}")` you can simply write `"${message}"`?

Comment: Off-topic but this works well on .NET and Mono https://github.com/logary/logary